# Show there is a unique $(x,y)$ satisfying this equation

Tags: calculus

For $(\alpha,\beta)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ be fixed, consider $f(x)=x^3-\alpha x+\beta$. Show that for any $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$, $x\not=y$, there exists a unique $(\alpha,\beta)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f(x)=f(y)=0$, and the function $F:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ that maps $(x,y)$ to $(\alpha,\beta)$ maps at most six different values to a single value.

My thought was that $f(x)=f(y)=0$ is equivalent to the matrix equation $\begin{bmatrix} -x & 1\\ -y & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\alpha\\ \beta\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-x^3\\-y^3\end{bmatrix}$. Since $x\not=y$, the matrix is invertible with unique solution $\begin{bmatrix}\alpha\\\beta\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}y^2+xy+x^2\\xy(x+y)\end{bmatrix}$.

Is this approach correct, and are there alternatives? Also, I don't see why the function $F$ maps at most six different values to one.

Comment: It looks fine thought the wording of the problem, at the beginning, is a little odd to me: if $\;(\alpha,\,\beta)\in\Bbb R^2\;$ is **fixed**, how come immediately after this for any element in the plane there exists $\;(\alpha,\,\beta)\in\Bbb R^2\;$ such that...etc.? I think the first pair $\;(\alpha,\,\beta)\;$ is *not* fixed, but for any $\;(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2,\,x\neq y\;$ there...etc.

Comment: Also, what does "$\,F\;$ maps...at most six different **values** to a single value" mean? Did you mean "points" (in the plane) instead of "values" in both cases?

Comment: The answer to the first question is correct! For the second, think about this: if $x,y$ are solution for a certain fixed pair $(\alpha,\beta)$, then they are zeros of a polynomial of degree 3. So, $(x,y)$ is a couple of elements picked from a set with three elements (the zeros of the polynomial): the possible couples are then 6.

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes, I guess it was worded a little poorly. I guess I meant $f:\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}$, and once we fix the $(\alpha,\beta)$ in the first component, find such $x,y$. And yes, I meant there are there no more than six points $q_1,...,q_6$ that $F$ maps to a single point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint (for the second part):   for given $\alpha,\beta\,$, the equation $\,z^3 - \alpha z + \beta = 0\,$ has roots $\,u,v,-u-v\,$. There are (at most) $\,6\,$ ways to choose $\,x,y\,$ from among them, in other words there are (at most) $\,6\,$ pairs $\,(x,y)\,$ which map to the same $\,\alpha,\beta\,$. There may be *less* than $\,6\,$ if the roots are not all real, or not all distinct.

Comment: How do you know that for a given $(\alpha,\beta)$, the polynomial splits over $\mathbb{R}$? Do you mean it can split into at most 3 distinct roots, and so there are at most 6 ways to choose two elements from the (at most) 3 element set?

Comment: @TomChalmer Right. The cubic has either $1$ or $3$ real roots. In the former case there exists no real pair $\,(x,y)\,$ with $\,x \ne y\,$ mapping to the respective $\,(\alpha,\beta)\,$, in the latter case there are at most $\,6\,$ such. I edited the answer to cover that point.